# MSMQ, handling WM_COPYDATA in c++

Tags: c++, ipc, msmq

I have two C++ console applications, and I want to implement inter-process communication so I can marshal custom message from app1 to app2.

using spy++, I am sure my sender application is doing fine, but somehow I can't manage to handle the message in the receiving app. According to the documents I am supposed to overload the messaging APIs in my receiver app but i can't. What am I supposed to do?

Can anyone help me with this issue please?
My sender app code is:

```
HWND HWnd = FindWindow(null,"Reciever")
LPTSTR lpszString =L"test";
COPYDATASTRUCT cdss;
cdss.dwData = 1; 
cdss.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR)* (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
cdss.lpData = lpszString;
SendMessage(HWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)HWnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cdss);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This cannot work in a console mode app, it doesn't own the window.  Use a pipe or socket instead.  Or a message queue.

Comment: yea thanks I've read it before :) didn't understand it though, is the msg the switch for case WM_COPYDATA ? if so, what API is being overloaded ??

Comment: @HansPassant I thought I am using message queue, aren't I ?

Comment: MSMQ has nothing to do with the windows message queue.

Comment: @HansPassant So you're saying I can't handle WM_COPYDATA in my console right? unless I create a window , just for handling the message ?

Comment: Creating a window is not enough, you also have to pump a message loop so you can detect messages being sent to the window.  Like WM_COPYDATA.  That's unpleasant to do in a console mode app, of course no problem at all in a GUI app.  Nothing that pretty about WM_COPYDATA anyway, you also need to know the correct window handle to send the message to.  Use a socket or pipe and you don't have those kind of problems.